# image not showing in laravel 8 after saving it in the storage folder

Tags: image, model-view-controller, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-9

i have saved the path of the image in my sql database, when i try to output the image in my view its not showing. any help

**This is my controller for the image saving**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $request->validate([
        'carImage' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif', 
    ]);
    $imagePath = $request->file('carImage')->store('public/images');
    $image = new Mycar(); 
    $image->description = request('description');
    $image->owner = request('owner');
    $image->rate_per_day = request('rate');
    $image->image = $imagePath;
    $image->save();
    $id = $request->session()->get('id');

    return redirect('user/mycars/' . $id)->with('success_mg', 'car uploaded successfully');
}
```

**This is where I want to show the image**

```
<div style=" width:60%;  margin: 20px auto;">
  <div class="text-center mb-2 mt-2">
  <img src="{{ asset('storage/'. $posts->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: none; max-height: 100%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 10px;"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try: <img src="{{ Storage::url($posts->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 100%; max-width: none; max-height: 100%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 10px;"/>

Comment: Did you create the symbolic link for "storage"? Try : php artisan storage:link

Comment: @BossCOTIGA yes please i did

Comment: @KarlHill used src="{{ Storage::url($posts->image) }}" but still image not showing, could it be the problem please

Comment: @KarlHill it worked perfectly, had to restart the server again, thanks